# Ruby axlsx pie chart title font size

Tags: ruby, axlsx

I'm using the axslx ruby gem to create a spreadsheet with a pie chart. For the most part it is very straightforward and I've had no problems with one exception: I can't figure out how to set the font size for the title in the pie chart. I've read through the documentation and examples and found no mention of it. I'm sure I have overlooked it but if anyone knows how to do that, I would appreciate any help.

thanks!

adding code ... sorry, should have provided this initially

```
issue_sheet.add_chart(Axlsx::Pie3DChart, start_at: 'I3', end_at: 'S32') do |chart|
    chart.add_series data: issue_sheet['G3:G7'], labels: issue_sheet['F3:F7'], colors: ['9467BD','D62828','EF7E12','82BBDD','3AA02B']
    chart.title = "Distribution by Severity"
    chart.d_lbls.show_val = false
    chart.d_lbls.show_percent = true
    chart.d_lbls.d_lbl_pos = :outEnd
    chart.d_lbls.show_leader_lines = true
end
```

I did notice something interesting but I'm not sure what it means. If I use a cell reference rather than a string for the chart.title, the font size changes.

```
chart.title = "Distribution by Severity" # this sets the font size to 16
chart.title = issue_chart['F2'] # this sets the font size to 10
```

Comment: Can you show your code, so it is easier to help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of sz property provided in this [link](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/lib/axlsx/stylesheet/font.rb#L108)

```
item_style = s.add_style :b => false, :sz => 9,  :font_name => 'courier'
row = sheet.add_row [item.name, item.price], :style => item_style
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this initially. I have made use of the sz property in styles and directly applying it to a cell but I have not been successful in applying it to a chart title. That's where I'm having trouble.